# Older JDK to use in IntelliJ Plugin Platform SDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm on the task of migrating an IntelliJ Plugin which is written in Java 7 to work with IntelliJ 2016.2. Currently development is still done under IntelliJ 13.
The plugin is currently not compatible with Java 8, or at least it's unclear.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to add an extra JDK 7 to my IntelliJ 2016.2 home to have the Platform Plugin SDK work with Java 7. Or is this impossible due to IntelliJ 2016.2 requiring Java 8 to run? I'm unsure and haven't found anything specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 is backward compatible, the plugin should work even if it was compiled with JDK 6, unless there was some API change in IntelliJ.

You can either compile with older IntelliJ and JDK 6/7 or IntelliJ 2016.2+ with JDK 8.